# How to solve Object reference not set to an instance of an object.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

In my asp.net program.I set one protected list.And i add a value in list.But it shows Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

```
protected List<string> list;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     list.Add("hai");
}
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to initialize the list first:

```
protected List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 31):

I think you just need;

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("hai");
```

There is a difference between

```
List<string> list;
```

and

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

When you didn't use [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword in this case, your `list` didn't initialized. And when you try to add it `hai`, obviously you get an error.