# ListBoxItem is null (NullReferenceException) even though it is initialized

Tags: c#, .net-core, uwp

I'm developing a UWP app where I need to display some contents of a file as entries in a ListBox like this:

[image]

I managed to read the file and use the parts that I want, but I stumbled upon an error that does not really make sense to me.

The app throws a NullReferenceException for a ListBoxItem array I'm using, even though I have initialized it before the for loop.

Here's part of the code I've written:

```
ListBoxItem[] item = new ListBoxItem[512]; //object initialization
for (int i = 0; i <= 511; i++)
{
    item[i].Content = "Preset " + (i + 1) + ":" + presets[i];
    //presets[] is an array I'm using to store the file contents before "merging" them to the item[] array
}
listBox1.Items.Clear();
listBox1.Items.Add(item); //after clearing the ListBox, display the contents of new file
```

I did check that part using breakpoints, and it seems that the item[] array is null, even though I have initialized it. I've also read other posts (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140047/how-to-solve-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)), which were mostly forgotten initializations. Part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/9931392) on NullReferenceException, however, suggests that the array is allocated but never really initialized.

I'm at a loss, since I did develop the same app in WinForms a while back with mostly the same code and it did not have an initialization problem.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

new ListBoxItem[512] initializes just an empty array. After this you need to create an object of ListBoxItem type and add it to one of the array cell you want.

try this

```
ListBoxItem[] item = new ListBoxItem[512]; //array initialization
for (int i = 0; i <= 511; i++)
{
ListBoxItem itm = new ListBoxItem();  //object initialization
itm.Content = "Preset " + (i + 1) + ":" + presets[i];
item[i]=itm;
}
```

Comment: It worked flawlessly. Thank you! Can you explain to me why do I need to initialize a second ListboxItem, though?

Comment: You are welcome.  I added some explanations to my answer.

Comment: I understand it now. Thank you again!